# fileEntry.delete(); not deleting the files

Tags: java, delete-file

The following code is correctly being executed. The problem is arising at the end of the outermost loop when i am trying to delete the file i have performed actions upon. After the fileEntry.delete(); the print statement shows the value of 'check' as false, i.e., files are not being deleted.

```
    for (File fileEntry : folderneg.listFiles())
    {
                temp = fileEntry.getPath();

                System.out.println("File= " + fileEntry +"   "+ ++cnttneg + "   " + ++dircnt);
                File file = new File(temp);
                Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));

                //To separate sentences
                scanInput.useDelimiter("\\n");
                ArrayList<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
                String theSentence;

                while(scanInput.hasNext())
                {
                        String next = scanInput.next();
                        theSentence = new String(next);
                        sentences.add(theSentence);
                }

                for (String sen: sentences)
                {

                     BufferedWriter bwneut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileneut.getAbsoluteFile()));
                     String indivual_sentence_of_a_line[] = sen.trim().split("\\.");                                

                    for (String one_review: indivual_sentence_of_a_line)
                    {
                      //some code
                    }
                    bwneut.write(write_all_neut);
                    bwneut.close();
                }
            boolean check = fileEntry.delete();
            System.out.println(check);
    }//end of for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the file before you can delete it:

```
scanInput.close();
```

---

You can create the `Scanner` using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to ensure it is closed automatically:

```
// open input
try (Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileEntry))) {
    // ... use the input in this block ...

    // the input is automatically closed when the try-with-resources block
    // is exited, even if an exception is thrown.
}
fileEntry.delete();
```